# random group generator in R

Tags: random, selection, variable-assignment

I have a data set consisting of 250 students from different schools and classrooms. For the experimental design, I would like to generate in a random manner 35 groups consisting of approx. 7 students in each group, and then after the first activity, break up the students as randomly as possible in to 25 groups of 10 students each. Is there a package and example of how I can perform this in R?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no relation between which groups students are in during the first and second activities, then it's the same problem twice over.

Assuming a student can only belong to one group at a time, just shuffle the array and pull out elements per your group size until there are no more left.

```
students=1:250;
rand_students=sample(students,length(students));
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the Sample package or any other package for that matter to assign students to groups and provide those in a new data set? For instance, a printout of a table or whatever stating the group number (G1) and the students in that group (82 126 140   6 159  56   9)....all the way to G35.